# possible combinations of 3-digit

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

How many possible combinations can a 3-digit safe code have?

Because there are 10 digits and we have to choice 3 digits from this,
 then we may get $10^P3$ but A author used the formula $n^r$, why is that. What the problem in my calculations?

Comment: What do you mean by $10^p 3$? Do you mean $10\cdot9\cdot8$? If so, you’re assuming that the $3$ digits must all be distinct, while the statement of the problem allows two or all three of them to be the same.

Comment: $ 10^P3 =\frac{10!}{3!}$

Comment: Okay; that’s normally written $_{10}P_3$, and it’s $\frac{10!}{7!}$.

Comment: $_{10}P_3=10!/7!=10\times9\times8$

Comment: 10 digits are different but  repetition are not allowed here, because we are expecting a possible combinations of 3 digit.

Comment: but answer is given 1000

Comment: To get $900$ they must be thinking of three digit numbers, where leading zeros are not allowed.  I would prefer $1000$, $720$ as you get, or even $810$ which doesn't allow two neighboring digits to $900$.

Comment: sorry Ross , I it was a typo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is exactly the one that I suspected in my comment. $_{10}P_3=\frac{10!}{3!}=10\cdot9\cdot8$. This is the number of ways of choosing a $3$-digit combination in which the three digits are all distinct: there are $10$ ways to choose the first digit, but then only $9$ choices remain for the second digit, and once those have been chosen only $8$ choices remain for the last digit.

The problem, however, does not require the digits to be distinct. Thus, there are $10$ choices for the first digit, and since you’re allowed to repeat digits, there are still $10$ choices available for the second digit, and again $10$ for the third. These choices can be made in $10\cdot10\cdot10=10^3$ different ways, so that’s the number of $3$-digit combinations.

As an independent check, notice that the $3$-digit combinations are just the integers from $0$ through $999$, padded on the left with zeros to bring them up to $3$ digits. There are $999$ integers from $1$ through $999$, and $000$ makes the thousandth, so there are $1000=10^3$ such integers.